# Internet Explorer Mode Compatibility - Issue

Tags: html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, doctype

I am using doctype

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
```

and meta

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE8" />
```

for IE 8 **Browser Mode** and **Document Mode**,

But i am getting **Browser Mode IE9** and **Document Mode IE8**

What should i do for **Browser Mode = IE8** and **Document Mode = IE8**.

I am confuse with IE version compatibility.

Comment: The the accepted answer to question “IE8 browser mode vs document mode” is broader, but it also addresses this specific problem. The browser mode cannot be set in the document. On the other hand, that mode only affects the user agent string set to servers and the version vector used to evaluate “conditional comments”.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela : how can i change browser mode?

Comment: you can change it using IE Developer Tools (F12), as a user, but not in your document as an author.